# symfony2 - mark options selected depending by data coming from the database - without doctrine

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this form:

```
class CampaignType extends AbstractType {

protected $pricings;

public function __construct(array $pricings){
    $this->pricings = $pricings;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

    $builder
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('code', 'text')
        ->add('pricings', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->pricings,
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

}

$pricing is a key value array passed to the form.

```
array(2) { 
    [2335331]=> string(38) "1 Months - 1 Issues - 34 - Credit card" 
    [2335332]=> string(40) "12 Months - 12 Issues - 23 - Credit card" 
    [2335333]=> string(40) "24 Months - 12 Issues - 23 - Credit card" 
}
```

Now when I need to edit the record, I pass a $defaultData to the form:

```
array(10) { 
  ["id"]=> string(1) "4" 
  ["subsite_id"]=> string(3) "104" 
  ["name"]=> string(5) "ffsgd" 
  ["code"]=> string(6) "dfgfdg" 
  ["pricings"]=> 
    array(2) { 
      [2335331]=> string(38) "1 Months - 1 Issues - 34 - Credit card" 
      [2335332]=> string(40) "12 Months - 12 Issues - 23 - Credit card" } }
```

but the multi select doesn't get the passed options as selected.

Is there any way to mark few options of a multi select widget as selected, depending by a key value array fetched from a database? Whithout using Doctrine

Comment: Pass the simple array of selected values to the `data` option of the `choice` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision) suggestion, the 'data' option must be used, just with a simple array of selected values, not a key value array like I thought.

So the Form declaration would look like this:

```
class CampaignType extends AbstractType {

  protected $pricings;

  public function __construct(array $pricings, array $selectedPricings){
    $this->pricings = $pricings;
    $this->selectedPricings;
  }

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

    $builder
      ->setMethod('POST')
      ->add('name', 'text')
      ->add('code', 'text')
      ->add('pricings', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $this->pricings,
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'data' => $this->selectedPricing      //array('2335331', '2335332')
      ))
      ->add('save', 'submit');
   }
}
```